Start counting candles after an EMA crossover until X number of them and stop to start looking for a pattern
*Hello firstable im new at Pine Script but i'm trying to do my best, the problem is


it does not execute

any position after i tried this

For the logic seems good, but in practice doesn't do what i need:
//@version=5  
strategy("Opt", overlay=true)  
// Variables for tracking states
var float stopLoss = na
var float takeProfit = na
var int entryBar = na
var bool inPosition = false
var float positionSize = na
var bool partialClosed = false
// crossovers EMA  
longSignal = ta.crossover(emaShort, emaLong)  
shortSignal = ta.crossunder(emaShort, emaLong) 
     if longSignal or shortSignal
        entryBar := bar_index
        label.new(bar_index, high, text="Signal", color=#af4c7d , style=label.style_circle)
    
  
capitalActual = strategy.equity  
riskAmount = capitalActual * riskPerTrade  
// Evaluate on the fourth bar
if not na(entryBar) and bar_index == entryBar + 4 and not inPosition
    label.new(bar_index, high, text="Evalúa 4ª vela", color=color.orange)
    if confirmLong
        // Long setup
        stopLoss := low[1] // Previous bearish bar
        takeProfit := close + (close - stopLoss) * riskRewardRatio
        inPosition := true
        partialClosed := false
        positionSize := riskAmount // Example size; adjust to your preference
        strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    if confirmShort
        // Short setup
        stopLoss := high[1] // Previous bullish bar
        takeProfit := close - (stopLoss - close) * riskRewardRatio
        inPosition := true
        partialClosed := false
        positionSize := riskAmount // Example size; adjust to your preference
        strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

// Manage open positions
if inPosition
    // Stop loss
    if (strategy.position_size > 0 and close <= stopLoss) or (strategy.position_size < 0 and close >= stopLoss)
        strategy.close_all()

    // Take profit
    if (strategy.position_size > 0 and close >= takeProfit) or (strategy.position_size < 0 and close <= takeProfit)
        if not partialClosed
            strategy.close("Partial Close", qty=positionSize * 0.8)
            partialClosed := true
        if (strategy.position_size > 0 and close < emaShort) or (strategy.position_size < 0 and close > emaShort)
            strategy.close_all()
if not inPosition
    stopLoss := na
    takeProfit := na
    entryBar := na
    inPosition := false
    positionSize := na
    partialClosed := false

What i really wanted the code to do is as written above; to set an entry long/short, firstable a longsingal or a shortsignal is given after a crossover or crossunder the EMA, then it has to wait for the next 4 candles to form, then look for new conditions to be met which are inside confirmLong and confirmShort variables, after this has to set SL and TP and update the rest of the variables inside the condition that has read that 4 bars already have passed and of course set a LONG OR A SHORT ENTRY.
I would really appriciate some help here, as im kinda lost from now on to be honest ):
EDIT:

I think the issue is that this condition is not fullfilling or counting properly (bar_index == entryBar + 4) or triggering the buy or sell after this condition is set to be true, aparently it never gets to be true thats why is not working i think? BECAUSE all other conditions as seen in the graph are being triggered both signals longSignal and confirmLong any knowledgeable around? :)--- maybe something to work around this method and use a different approach/condition so it can loop through the next 4 bars after the alert then stop and start looking around.

Your code does not compile, but you posted a screenshot of the script. Please upload the code again.
